# Diferrencing vs Moving Average

Tags: time-series, self-study, mathematical-statistics, seasonality, moving-average

**Moving Average** and **differencing** a series can both be used to remove seasonality. Does the difference of these two lie in the model they are used? Moving Average used in classical decomposition and Differencing in probabilistic modals?
I would like to know when each would be used and don't they serve the same purpose?To make a series stationary